# Using jquery.parseJSON with JavaScriptSerializer (how to get double quote escaping)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, jquery-templates

I've run into a problem displaying a jQuery template where the JSON is written directly into the HTML, and then passed to jquery templates on load to render a part of the screen.

I have a simple function that loads the template:

```
function templateLoader(templateID, containerID, serializedData) {
    var json = $.parseJSON(serializedData);
    $("#" + templateID).tmpl(json).appendTo("#" + containerID);
};
```

This is failing, saying the JSON is invalid.  Here's what the caller looks like:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(function () {
    templateLoader('questionTemplate', 
      'questionContainer', 
      '[{"ID":1,"Text":"something with an escaped \"double quote\" and a single quote does the unicode version\u0027s end of string"}]');
});
</script>
```

The JSON is produced by a call to JavaScriptSerializer.serialize() and output in a ASP.NET MVC view with <%= JavaScriptSerializer.serialize(model.questions) %>

The JSON itself passes the various JSON validation tests.

I understand that javascript itself is escaping the double quotes, leaving the double quotes naked for the call to jQuery's parseJSON().

My question is where best to fix this?  Should I post process the JavaScriptSerializer serialize call to add additional escaping or change from escaping to doing &quot; replacements?  This seems like it would be a more common problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're embedding it, why use JSON or `JSON.parse` at all?  Why not just literals:

```
templateLoader('questionTemplate', 
  'questionContainer', 
  [{"ID":1,"Text":"something with an escaped \"double quote\" and a single quote does the unicode version\u0027s end of string"}]);
```

Clearly, you have to modify `templateLoader` accordingly.  You can change `serializedData` to `json` (except that the name is misleading, since `json` is actually an array, *not* a JSON string), then delete the first line of the function.

Comment: It's true, just use the raw literal being serialized, the jQuery template will take it as is, no need to further parse it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

(for some one who fighting the same issue)

Use `HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode`

Your server tag will become like

```
<%= HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(JavaScriptSerializer.serialize(model.questions)) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(function () {
    templateLoader('questionTemplate', 
      'questionContainer', 
      '[{"ID":1,"Text":"something with an escaped \\\"double quote\\\" and a single quote does the unicode version\u0027s end of string"}]');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, that does work.  Though, my question is really how to best do this encoding.  Since, I'm using the JavaScriptSerializer class in .NET.  I can certainly post-process what it does, and add additional backslashes, but to escape the escape across both C# and Javascript is awkward, so curious if others had found better solutions.